# Save PDF on Server with generated QRCode(png) and JSPDF

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jspdf

I am trying to save a generated PDF which generates a PDF out of a "div" and save it to my Server.

I got it working with JSPdf that it saves the PDF on the Server. The problem is that i have an image inside my div. It's a generated QRCode. And when I open the PDF, the generated QRCode looks like this.

[image: failed save]

I think the problem is in the sending process to my "upload.php", because when i use JSPDF to localy save that div, the QRCode is shown properly.

```
$("#printer").on("click",function(e){

   var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#qrcode')[0], 15, 15, {  //"#qrcode" is the div which should be saved
      'background': '#fff',
    }, function() {
      doc.save('sample-file.pdf');

    var pdf =doc.output();
    var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , pdf);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'post', 'upload.php', true ); //Post to php Script to save to server
    xhr.send(data);


    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/test.pdf';

    });

});
```

This is my "upload.php" Code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = "test.pdf"; // name the file
    $file = fopen("uploads/" .$fname, 'w'); // open the file path
    fwrite($file, $data); //save data
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "No Data Sent";
}
?>
```

The QRcode is a .png File. And is displayed in "#qrcode". 
I hope somebody can help me displaying my QRCode correctly also on my Server.

Thanks in advance.